# Kommasetzung/Punctuation: Aber (,) dass die Reichen immer reicher werden (,) ist komisch

Tags: grammaticality, comma

Welche Schreibweise ist richtig, und warum? Which one is correct, and why?

> 1. Aber, dass die Reichen immer reicher werden, ist komisch.
> 2. Aber dass die Reichen immer reicher werden, ist komisch.
> 3. Aber dass die Reichen immer reicher werden ist komisch.

Comment: Es gibt einen Unterschied zwischen _Dass aber die Reichen immer reicher werden, ist komisch_ und _Dass die Reichen immer reicher werden, ist aber komisch._, oder?

Comment: Ja. Da steht das *aber* jedoch woanders...

Comment: Jo, das sollte auch keine Antwort sein. Ich würde die erste Variante wählen, weil ich es zu _Aber (es) ist komisch, dass die Reichen immer reicher werden._ umstellen könnte/würde. Ich behaupte es kommt darauf an welche Funktion das _aber_ haben soll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Originalsatz:** Aber<sub>(</sub>,<sub>)</sub> dass die Reichen immer reicher werden<sub>(</sub>,<sub>)</sub> ist komisch.

Wenn wir den Satz zerlegen, erhalten wir

> **Hauptsatz:** Aber *es* ist komisch.
>
> **Nebensatz:** dass die Reichen immer reicher werden.

Das Pronomen *es* ist im Originalsatz durch den Nebensatz ersetzt worden. Bezüglich der Kommas schauen wir nun im aktuellen [amtlichen Regelwerk](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6201#) (2018) nach. Dort steht:

> **§ 74** Nebensätze grenzt man mit Komma ab; sind sie eingeschoben, so schließt man sie mit paarigem Komma ein.

Dieser Fall liegt hier vor, demnach muss im Originalsatz an beiden Stellen ein Komma stehen:

> Aber, dass die Reichen immer reicher werden, ist komisch.

Comment: §74 E1 könnte hier aber auch gelten. Beispielsatz dort: "Ich habe sie selten besucht, aber wenn ich bei ihr war, saßen wir bis spät in die Nacht zusammen." Es kommt darauf an, ob  das "Aber" Teil des Haupt- oder Teil des Nebensatzes ist. Das kann man nur wissen, wenn man die Sätze davor kennt.